# how to pass class as a parameter to a static method

Tags: java, android, service

i am creating a control class to know if a service is running or not as shown in the following code

```
public class CServiceCtrl {
private final static String TAG = ActMain.class.getSimpleName();

public static boolean isRunning(Activity act, Class servClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) act.getSystemService(act.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (servClass.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {//highlighted with red "unknown class servClass"
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
    }
}
```

and in onCreate of the main activity I call the follwoing code where ServSimulator is the name of the service:

```
CServiceCtrl.isRunning(this, ServSimulator.class);
```

but the code cant be compiled because the servClass in the if-statement above is underscored in red and the error says "unknown class servClass".
how to solve this error

Comment: try to replace "public static boolean isRunning(Activity act, Class servClass)" with "public static boolean isRunning(Activity act, class servClass)", i hope it will work.

Comment: @pooyan: That won't compile.

Comment: even after replacing?

Comment: @pooyan That can't work. `class` is reserved keyword in Java. Type which can be used as method parameter which represent *type* is `java.lang.Class` (preferably with generic type or wildcard).

Comment: there is a trick that it comes in my mind . do you want to use exact your code or you are welcome with trick?

Comment: @pooyan i solved it, by replacing servClass.class.getName() with servClass.getName()

Answer (score 1):

`servClass` is already a `Class` object. Don't use `servClass.class` in the `if` statement; just `servClass` by itself.

```
if (servClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName()))
```